# R: Dividing a Number into N Parts such that Some Conditions are Met

Tags: r

I am working with the R programming language.

Here is my problem:

Suppose I have 11 candies (candy_1, candy_2... candy_11). **I want to assign a number ("weight") to each one of these candies such that:**

- The sum of all numbers is 1
- Any given number can only be between 0 and 1
- Candy_6 has the highest number and this number is 0.5
- Candy_6 > Candy_7 > Candy_8 > Candy_9 > Candy_10 > Candy_11
- Candy_6> Candy_5 > Candy_4 > Candy_3 > Candy_2 > Candy_1
- Candy_7 = Candy_5, Candy_8 = Candy_4, Candy_9 = Candy_3, Candy_10 = Candy_2, Candy_11 = Candy_1
- Note: I am basically making a discrete normal distribution of candy weights centered around Candy_6)

After spending a long time thinking about this question, I think I was able to think of an approximate way to solve this problem where the weights are sequentially divided between the remaining candies:

```
generate_sequence <- function(n, pos, max_val) {
  
  other_val <- (1 - max_val) / (n - 1)
  

  seq <- rep(other_val, n)
  
  seq[pos] <- max_val
  
  for (i in 1:n) {
    distance <- abs(i - pos)
    seq[i] <- seq[i] - distance * other_val / (n / 2)
  }
  
  return(seq)
}


print(data.frame(candy_number = seq(1:11), weights = generate_sequence(11, 6, 0.5)))

   candy_number     weights
1             1 0.004545455
2             2 0.013636364
3             3 0.022727273
4             4 0.031818182
5             5 0.040909091
6             6 0.500000000
7             7 0.040909091
8             8 0.031818182
9             9 0.022727273
10           10 0.013636364
11           11 0.004545455
```

**Optional: Visualization**

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(df, aes(x = factor(candy_number), y = weights)) +
    geom_bar(stat = "identity", fill = "steelblue") +
    theme_minimal() +
    labs(x = "Candy Number", y = "Weights", title = "Candy Weights Distribution") +
    theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1))
```

[image]

**My Question:** I am trying to modify this function so that it can handle more constraints. For example:

- Situation 1: Suppose now I want the weight of candy_1 and candy_11 to be equal to a certain number.
- Situation 2: Or, suppose now I want the candy_9 to have the highest weight, and have candies 10,11 have monotonically decreasing weight on one side and candies 1-8 have monotonically  decreasing weights on the other side

How can I redefine this function to respect all these constraints for Situation 1? How can I redefine this function to respect all these constraints for Situation 2?

Thanks!

- **Related Question:** https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4804927/calculating-the-probabilities-of-a-100-sided-weighted-dice

Comment: Very interesting question but since this post is not about non-working programming code, consider asking on other StackExchange sites (CrossValidated, CodeReview, DataScience) and keep question specific and not for open-ended constraints. This sounds like an optimization question with multiple variable constraints.

Comment: @ Parfait: thank you for your reply! I wanted to be transparent and post the original motivations for this question, my objectives, what I tried so far, etc. I can ask a more direct question if this would be better suited. Please let me know - thank you so much!

Comment: I like your `generate_sequence`. That it does one thing...functions should be like that, but what 'things in the world' have that distribution? You should perhaps track down papers by Emanuel Parzen and his disciples who did a fair bit of work in R.  Just for light reading.

Comment: @Chris: thank you for this suggestion! I will look into this reference!

Comment: If you want some "flexibility", I suggest you draft a code to show what you really want. In your "**My Question**", you have two different objectives (definitely different constraints). It is too vague for other to know what you really want.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that each adjacent pair among w<sub>7</sub>, w<sub>8</sub>, w<sub>9</sub>, w<sub>10</sub> and w<sub>11</sub> differ from each other by a constant amount `d`, which is to be determined.

We therefore have the following.

w<sub>10</sub> =                      w<sub>11</sub> +     d

w<sub>9</sub>  = w<sub>10</sub> + d = w<sub>11</sub> + 2 * d

w<sub>8</sub>  = w<sub>9</sub>  + d = w<sub>11</sub> + 3 * d

w<sub>7</sub>  = w<sub>8</sub>  + d = w<sub>11</sub> + 4 * d

---

We know that

2 * (w<sub>7</sub> + w<sub>8</sub> + w<sub>9</sub> + w<sub>10</sub> + w<sub>11</sub>) + w<sub>6</sub> = 1

or

2 * (5 * w<sub>11</sub> + (1 + 2 + 3 + 4) * d) + 0.5 = 1

or

10 * w<sub>11</sub> + 20 * d = 0.5

or

d = (0.5 - 10 * w<sub>11</sub>)/20 = 0.025 - 0.5 * w<sub>11</sub>

---

In order that d >= 0 we require

0 <= w<sub>11</sub> <= 0.025/0.5

or

0 <= w<sub>11</sub> <= 0.05

---

If, for example, we set

w<sub>11</sub> = 0.01

then

d = 0.025 - 0.5 * 0.01 = 0.02

so

w<sub>11</sub> =                         0.01

w<sub>10</sub> = w<sub>11</sub> + 0.02 = 0.03

w<sub>9</sub>  = w<sub>10</sub> + 0.02 = 0.05

w<sub>8</sub>  = w<sub>9</sub>  + 0.02 = 0.07

w<sub>7</sub>  = w<sub>8</sub>  + 0.02 = 0.09

Total = 0.25

Of course,

w<sub>5</sub> = w<sub>7</sub>  = 0.09

w<sub>4</sub> = w<sub>8</sub>  = 0.07

w<sub>3</sub> = w<sub>9</sub>  = 0.05

w<sub>2</sub> = w<sub>10</sub> = 0.03

w<sub>1</sub> = w<sub>11</sub> = 0.01

As expected,

2 * 0.25 + 0.50 = 1.0

---

Now suppose,

w<sub>11</sub> = 0.04

then

d = 0.025 - 0.5 * 0.04 = 0.005

so

w<sub>11</sub> =                          0.040

w<sub>10</sub> = w<sub>11</sub> + 0.005 = 0.045

w<sub>9</sub>  = w<sub>10</sub> + 0.005 = 0.050

w<sub>8</sub>  = w<sub>9</sub>  + 0.005 = 0.055

w<sub>7</sub>  = w<sub>8</sub>  + 0.005 = 0.060

Total = 0.250

Again,

2 * 0.25 + 0.50 = 1.0

Comment: @ Cary Swoveland: thank you so much for your answer!

Answer (score 1):

Here's an approach that gives everything relative weights and then allocates the amount to be distributed based on the relative weights.

For the other scenarios, it also has the option of assigning set values as well as having the max value be calculated, although it ignores the set values in that calculation.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(ggplot2)

# setup graph function to view results
graph_it <- function(df) {
  ggplot(df, aes(x = factor(candy_number), y = weights)) +
    geom_bar(stat = "identity", fill = "steelblue") +
    theme_minimal() +
    labs(x = "Candy Number", y = "Weights", title = "Candy Weights Distribution") +
    theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1))
}

# new sequence generator
gen2 <- function(n, max_val_pos, max_val = NA, other_set_values = NA) {
  # create framework to store results
  framework <- data.frame(f_pos = 1:n, f_value = NA, tmp_value = 0)

  # assign max value, if given
  if (!is.na(max_val)) {
    framework$f_value[max_val_pos] <- max_val
  }

  # assign other set values if present
  if (any(!is.na(other_set_values)) | (length(other_set_values) > 1)) {
    framework$f_value[as.numeric(names(other_set_values))] <- other_set_values
  }

  empty_value_positions <- framework$f_pos[is.na(framework$f_value)]

  # determine what is to the left and right of max val position
  left_side <- empty_value_positions[empty_value_positions < max_val_pos]
  right_side <- empty_value_positions[empty_value_positions > max_val_pos]


  longest_side <- max(length(left_side), length(right_side))

  # create weights for each side
  if (length(left_side) > 0) {
    framework$tmp_value[left_side] <- (longest_side - length(left_side) + 1):longest_side
  }

  if (length(right_side) > 0) {
    framework$tmp_value[right_side] <- longest_side:(longest_side - length(right_side) + 1)
  }

  # if no max val was given, give it the the highest weight to get the highest
  # weight to get the highest value of non-set values
  if (is.na(max_val)) {
    framework$tmp_value[max_val_pos] <- longest_side + 1
  }

  return(
    framework %>%
      mutate(f_value = replace_na(f_value, 0) +
        (
          (tmp_value / sum(.data$tmp_value)) * # proportion of remaining amount to be distributed
            (1 - sum(.data$f_value, na.rm = TRUE)) # remaining amount to be distributed
        )) %>%
      select(-tmp_value)
  )
}

# Scenario - original
data.frame(
  candy_number = seq(1:11),
  weights = gen2(
    n = 11,
    max_val_pos = 6,
    max_val = 0.5
  ) %>%
    pull(f_value)
) %>%
  graph_it()

# scenario 1
data.frame(
  candy_number = seq(1:11),
  weights = gen2(
    n = 11,
    max_val_pos = 6,
    max_val = 0.5,
    other_set_values = c("1" = .2, "11" = .2)
  ) %>%
    pull(f_value)
) %>%
  graph_it()

# scenario 2 - max val not given, just max location given.
# ignores set value in determining max value

data.frame(
  candy_number = seq(1:11),
  weights = gen2(
    n = 11,
    max_val_pos = 9,
    max_val = NA,
    other_set_values = c("1" = .2, "11" = .2)
  ) %>%
    pull(f_value)
) %>%
  graph_it()
```

Answer (score 1):

I have another approach
I use two series of numbers
[d<sub>1</sub>..d<sub>11</sub>] for weight between numbers
[w<sub>1</sub>..w<sub>11</sub>] for normalize weight between numbers and always Σw must be 1

let's suppose we want w<sub>6</sub>=0.5, So sum of other normalize weight must be 0.5 too
A = Σw - w<sub>6</sub> = 1 - 0.5 = 0.5
let's suppose we have binomial distribution for others, so we have
[image]
d<sub>1</sub>=1
d<sub>2</sub>=10
d<sub>3</sub>=45
d<sub>4</sub>=120
d<sub>5</sub>=210
and
d<sub>7</sub>=210
d<sub>8</sub>=120
d<sub>9</sub>=45
d<sub>10</sub>=10
d<sub>11</sub>=1
Σd = 2×(1+10+45+120+210) = 772

now we calculate each w like this:
w<sub>n</sub>=A*d<sub>n</sub>/Σd

w<sub>1</sub>=0.5×1/772=0.000647668
w<sub>2</sub>=0.5×10/772=0.006476684
w<sub>3</sub>=0.5×45/772=0.029145078
w<sub>4</sub>=0.5×120/772=0.077720207
w<sub>5</sub>=0.5×210/772=0.136010363
w<sub>7</sub>=0.5×210/772=0.136010363
w<sub>8</sub>=0.5×120/772=0.077720207
w<sub>9</sub>=0.5×45/772=0.029145078
w<sub>10</sub>=0.5×10/772=0.006476684
w<sub>11</sub>=0.5×1/772=0.000647668
and
d<sub>6</sub>=w<sub>6</sub>×Σd/A=0.5×772/0.5=772

[image]

**Situation 1:**

let's suppose we want w<sub>6</sub>=0.5, w<sub>1</sub>=0.1 and w<sub>11</sub>=0.1 So sum of other normalize weight must be 0.3
A = Σw - w<sub>6</sub> - w<sub>1</sub> - w<sub>11</sub> = 1 - 0.1 - 0.1 = 0.3
let's suppose we have same weight like previous for others, so we have
d<sub>2</sub>=10
d<sub>3</sub>=45
d<sub>4</sub>=120
d<sub>5</sub>=210
and
d<sub>7</sub>=210
d<sub>8</sub>=120
d<sub>9</sub>=45
d<sub>10</sub>=10
Σd = 2×(10+45+120+210) = 770

now we calculate each w like this:
w<sub>n</sub>=A*d<sub>n</sub>/Σd

w<sub>2</sub>=0.3×10/770=0.003896104
w<sub>3</sub>=0.3×45/770=0.017532468
w<sub>4</sub>=0.3×120/770=0.046753247
w<sub>5</sub>=0.3×210/770=0.081818182
w<sub>7</sub>=0.3×210/770=0.081818182
w<sub>8</sub>=0.3×120/770=0.046753247
w<sub>9</sub>=0.3×45/770=0.017532468
w<sub>10</sub>=0.3×10/770=0.003896104
and
d<sub>6</sub>=w<sub>6</sub>×Σd/A=0.5×770/0.3=1283.33333333
d<sub>1</sub>=w<sub>1</sub>×Σd/A=0.1×770/0.3=256.66666667
d<sub>11</sub>=w<sub>11</sub>×Σd/A=0.1×770/0.3=256.66666667

[image]

**Situation 2:**

let's suppose we want w<sub>9</sub>=0.5, So sum of other normalize weight must be 0.5 too
A = Σw - w<sub>6</sub> = 1 - 0.5 = 0.5
let's suppose we have binomial distribution for others, so we have
but in this situation n = 9 × 2 - 1 = 17
[image]

d<sub>1</sub>=1
d<sub>2</sub>=16
d<sub>3</sub>=120
d<sub>4</sub>=560
d<sub>5</sub>=1820
d<sub>6</sub>=4368
d<sub>7</sub>=8008
d<sub>8</sub>=11440
d<sub>10</sub>=11440
d<sub>11</sub>=8008
Σd = (1+16+120+560+1820+4368)+2×(8008+11440) = 45781

now we calculate each w like this:
w<sub>n</sub>=A*d<sub>n</sub>/Σd

w<sub>1</sub>=0.5×1/45781=0.0000109216
w<sub>2</sub>=0.5×16/45781=0.000174745
w<sub>3</sub>=0.5×120/45781=0.001310587
w<sub>4</sub>=0.5×560/45781=0.006116074
w<sub>5</sub>=0.5×1820/45781=0.019877242
w<sub>6</sub>=0.5×4368/45781=0.04770538
w<sub>7</sub>=0.5×8008/45781=0.087459863
w<sub>8</sub>=0.5×11440/45781=0.124942662
w<sub>10</sub>=0.5×11440/45781=0.124942662
w<sub>11</sub>=0.5×8008/45781=0.087459863
and
d<sub>9</sub>=w<sub>6</sub>×Σd/A=0.5×45781/0.5=45781

[image]